# Ant Ivy: heap out of memory: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, memory, ant, garbage-collection

I have a ant project, and builds successfully. But when I tried to run my PageRank program: etc/run.sh SequentialPageRank -input inputDirectory -output rankScore.txt -jump 0.15. The terminal returned following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:480)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:309)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:839)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:906)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2162)
at edu.umd.cloud9.example.pagerank.SequentialPageRank.main(SequentialPageRank.java:123).
```

As I estimated, the SequentialPageRank program need about 5G-10G memory. I run this program in a remote super server which has total 120G memory. So memory should be enough. I googled and found that's due to small memory heap size. Therefore, I tried three different solutions:

```
1. export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx10000m", run this command in terminal and rebuilt by enter "ant" command.
2. Modify build.xml. 
<target name="compile" depends="init,resolve" description="compile the source ">
   <javac encoding="UTF-8" classpathref="lib.path.id" srcdir="${src.dir}/dist" destdir="${build.dir}" optimize="on" debug="on">
       <compilerarg line="-J-Xms128m -J-Xmx10000m -Xlint:unchecked" />
   </javac>
</target>
3. Modify build.xml like 2. But I modified javac option fork="true", which will fork a new JVM instead of using default ant JVM.
```

However, the above 3 solutions neither worked. I am sure above 3 modifications were both run correctly, e.g, I typed echo $ANT_OPTS and it shown "-Xms128m -Xmx10000m". I didn't know how to solve this question, does anyone know a solution? thanks very much!

Comment: The compiler does not need that much memory, it's the JRE which is executing your compiled code (`java -cp ...` inside your run.sh script) that needs the memory!

Comment: wow! That may be the problem! Thanks! Let me try.

Comment: That's the question...Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying this JVM option `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

Comment: add this option to <compilerarg />?

Comment: No, provide this arg to the app running script `java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC ... SequentialPageRank`